# Is anomaly detection only done using deep learning? Or can you use something like a random forest model to detect anomalies?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, random-forest, anomaly-detection

Is anomaly detection only done using deep learning? Or can you use something like a random forest model to detect anomalies? For reference, I'm performing classification with a binary response. My dataset is fairly large (several million rows) with about 99.6% and 0.4% in each of the binary classes. I'm curious to see if there are ways to improve random forest to handle such cases.

Comment: Haven't come across this before, thank you, good to know! I'll be curious to see if the sparklyR package can implement this one.

Comment: Deep learning may or may not be useful depending on the problem, but it's certainly not required. There's a whole body of literature and techniques for anomaly detection that predate modern deep learning

Comment: @user20160 thank you, this is what I needed. I will look into these methods for anomaly detection.

Answer (score 2):

[isolation-forest](/questions/tagged/isolation-forest) is a method that uses randomized decision tress (similar to random forest) to identify outliers/anomalies in data sets.

"[Isolation Forest](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf?q=isolation-forest)" by Fei Tony Liu, Kai Ming Ting and Zhi-Hua Zhou.

> Most existing model-based approaches to anomaly detection construct a profile of normal instances, then identify instances that do not conform to the normal profile as
> anomalies. This paper proposes a fundamentally different
> model-based method that explicitly isolates anomalies instead of profiles normal points. To our best knowledge, the
> concept of isolation has not been explored in current literature. The use of isolation enables the proposed method,
> iForest, to exploit sub-sampling to an extent that is not feasible in existing methods, creating an algorithm which has a
> linear time complexity with a low constant and a low memory requirement. Our empirical evaluation shows that iForest performs favourably to ORCA, a near-linear time complexity distance-based method, LOF and Random Forests in
> terms of AUC and processing time, and especially in large
> data sets. iForest also works well in high dimensional problems which have a large number of irrelevant attributes,
> and in situations where training set does not contain any
> anomalies